# Optimising a simple mathematical calculation over list

Tags: python, optimization

I have a script where I am computing:

```
def sumsquared(arr):
    sum = 0
    idx = 0
    len = arr.__len__()
    while idx < (len - 1):
            sum = sum + (arr[idx] * arr[idx]) + (arr[idx+1] * arr[idx+1])
            idx = idx + 2

    return sum
```

The above function is called in a loop which populates two lists and calls this function twice: First time with a list of len ~ 1024 items and second time with len ~ 44100 items. The loop itself can run anywhere from 100 to 100000 times depending upon the input.

For a small sized input, `cProfile` based profiling informs me:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall  filename:lineno(function)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 2560   12.065   0.005    12.065    0.005    beat.py:8(sumsquared)
```

which is about 95% of the total running time for the script. Is there some way I can get some speed up on the function?

Comment: you should be able to use len = len(arr), no need to call .__len__()

Comment: @monkut that won't work because `len` is a local variable in the function which will prevent access to the builtin `len()`. WeaklyTyped should however be able to do `length = len(arr)`

Comment: yes, or just use len(arr) itself instead of creating a variable.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't len(arr) be called each time the loop checks for condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fastest I can find

```
from itertools import imap
from operator import mul
def sumsquared(arr):
    return sum(imap(mul, arr, arr))
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function is very strange.  All it does is compute the sum of the squares of the elements, except that it throws away the last element if there are an odd number of elements.  You add them two at a time for some reason, but that doesn't affect the end result.

To make it faster, you could use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) instead of writing your own function.

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> sumsquared(x)
30
>>> (x[:2*(len(x)//2)]**2).sum()
30
```

In general, if you have lists of thousands of numbers, using numpy arrays instead is likely to bring a major performance gain.

Comment: Converting to and from numpy arrays is expensive. It usually only makes sense if you are doing a bunch of operations together.

Comment: @gnibbler: True, but that's why I added the bit at the end.  If you have lists of 44000 numbers, you should probably just be using numpy arrays from the start.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for the [*itertools module*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools):

```
def sumsquared(arr):
    s = sum(itertools.imap(operator.mul, arr, arr))
    return s - arr[-1] ** 2 if len(arr) & 1 else s
```

The use of *sum*, *operator*, and *itertools* will eliminate almost all of the pure python overhead.

Also, *sum* has been optimized to run at nearly C speed when the inputs are ints, floats, or some mix of the two.  It is able to accumulate running totals without creating pure python objects for every intermediate subtotal.

Credit: Robert King for the idea of subtracting the final square when necessary.

One other note, if you're interested in obtaining high accuracy (i.e. minimizing loss of precision), consider using [*math.fsum*](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.fsum) instead of *sum*.

Comment: Maybe so, but you could be a little more specific.

Comment: `pairwise` returns `(s0,s1),(s1,s2)` where the question asks for `(s0,s1),(s2,s3)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum([i**2 for i in arr]) - (arr[-1]**2 if len(arr) % 2 else 0)
```

Comment: You should really do `sum(i**2 for i in arr)` instead. Your method will compute the entire list and then iterate over that list to sum the elements. I'm suggesting a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension. In my tests, the generator comprehension reduces runtime to almost 50% of the OP's algorithm

Comment: guido said this today "I'm -0 on using generator[ expression]s unless you know you have huge lists of values to iterate over. The concrete list [comprehension] is usually faster than the genexpr until memory allocation becomes critical." - https://plus.google.com/s/guido